# how to use values in other columns to fill nan of one column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to fill `nan` value with values in other columns, for example
I have a `df` like this:

```
col1, col2, col3, col4
1     nan    nan   nan
2     3      nan   nan
4     nan    5     nan
6     8      nan   9
```

I need to turn the `df` above into

```
col1, col2, col3, col4
1     nan    nan     1
2       3    nan     2
4     nan      5     4
6     8      nan     9
```

I want to iterate through `col1` ~ `col3`, and get the first available value there is for that row and use the value to replace the `nan` in `col4`, however if the row in `col4` already have value then ignore that row.

I was informed that looping over dataframe is not ideal, what other options do I have?

Comment: Why is your col1 row 2 changing from 2 to nan? Inconsistent with the question. Please do correct  it

Comment: it was a typo, thanks for that

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
df.assign(col4 = df.apply(lambda row: row[row.first_valid_index()], axis=1))
```

**Output:**

```
   col1,col2,col3,col4
0   1.0 NaN NaN 1.0
1   NaN 3.0 NaN 3.0
2   4.0 NaN 5.0 4.0
3   6.0 8.0 NaN 6.0
```

---

```
df.assign(col4 = df.apply(lambda row: row.first_valid_index(), axis=1))
```

This will give you:

```
   col1,col2,col3,col4
0   1.0 NaN NaN col1,
1   NaN 3.0 NaN col2,
2   4.0 NaN 5.0 col1,
3   6.0 8.0 NaN col1,
```

By using those information you can assign the values.

**Better use:**

```
df['col4'] = df.apply(
    lambda row: row[row.first_valid_index()] if np.isnan(row['col4']) else row['col4'],
    axis=1
)
```

This will give you the desired result(since we have to fill NaN of col4)

```
   col1,col2,col3,col4
0   1.0 NaN NaN 1.0
1   NaN 3.0 NaN 3.0
2   4.0 NaN 5.0 4.0
3   6.0 8.0 NaN 9.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `bfill` and `fillna`

```
df['col4'] = df['col4'].fillna(df.bfill(1)['col1'])

Out[833]:
   col1  col2  col3  col4
0     1   NaN   NaN   1.0
1     2   3.0   NaN   2.0
2     4   NaN   5.0   4.0
3     6   8.0   NaN   9.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `fillna` and loop over the names of the column:

```
for col_name in df.columns[:-1]:
    df['col4'].fillna(df[col_name], inplace=True)
```

That will give you:

```
   col1  col2  col3  col4
0     1   NaN   NaN   1.0
1     2   3.0   NaN   2.0
2     4   NaN   5.0   4.0
3     6   8.0   NaN   9.0
```